# minimum IE9 browser requirement and other equivalent browser versions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a web app that has a requirement for IE9. What is the equivalent browser versions for other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc) ?

I know how to check the user's current browser/version and if it is not supported I need to see if I can proving links for user to download latest browser.

the client code is in AngularJS

additional info:
I have many users still use IE8, some users would like for the website to pop up a message that their browser is unsupported and will not function properly with features of the site. Also they would like to get some kind of notification on what other equivalent browser versions would work for them.

Comment: There isn't an equivalent version for other browsers. IE9 Supports a set of JS and CSS specifications, Chrome, FF support the same and some more, what you are asking is to detect what CSS and JS features the IE9 supports and then check if that set of features are supported in Chrome, firefox, opera etc... If YES your web app will have to support this browsers versions, if NOT you can show a browser notice saying something like: "Sir, your browser is outdated!"

Check this link: http://outdatedbrowser.com/en
and http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/

Answer (score 2):

You are making a huge assumption that both Chrome and Firefox operate the same as IE8/7/6, and users of those browsers would have old outdated versions.

Chrome and Firefox have built-in update services. The only way the browsers would be outdated is if the user/administrator disabled that update service. If it's been disabled, then what's the point of directing them to a page to install a different browser.

AngularJS had very **specific** code to address support of IE8, and that code was just for IE8. What they have done in version 1.3 is discontinue updating and testing for that browser. It added extra work for them and offered no value.

The market share for IE8 is very small, and even smaller is the segment that will change browsers because you asked them too.

You shouldn't get caught up in management of browser versions. Write better JavaScript that doesn't execute extensions unless they are supported. Test your source code across multiple browsers. etc.. etc..

Comment: Exactly.  Designing/testing for specific versions is a way to madness, especially given the frequency of updates, even for IE11.  Instead, focus on experiences.  Design your site with a rich experience and a basic one.  That way, if someone comes in with a browser you've never heard of, they'll still have a good experience.  This way, you design two sites, not one for each version of each browser you know of.

Comment: I have specific clients that still on IE8. In a perfect world, sure, I will design a perfect site. But in reality, if you got hand over with an older project, there is always budget/time/management involved that you just do your best.

Comment: @AnnieC use the tools that were popular for web development back in 2009 and build something that works in IE8. No one working on modern frameworks in 2014 cares that you have clients stuck in the past.

Comment: @Mathew,good point. that's what I feel about most 'modern' web developers, unfortunately these clients who stuck in the past (legacy systems) pay big bugs for us to support them. That's why I am here asking :)